# Carriage return produces odd behavior in Python using the [end = ] parameter

Tags: python, return, escaping

> carriage_return = "I will use a carriage\rreturn"

working as expected:

input

> print(carriage_return)

output

> return use a carriage

> print(carriage_return, end = '\n')

> return use a carriage

not as expected:

> print(carriage_return, end = '')

output (where's the text that should follow "return"?)

> return

I expected:

> return use a carriage

if I go to an interactive python session, I get:

, >>> print(carriage_return, end = '')

> return>>>  a carriage

with my cursor between the arrows and the first 'a'
character. (As expected)

So there's a discrepancy there.

Am I misunderstanding something about how carriage
return works, or how the end='' statement works?

Answer (score 0):

`\r` returns the character to the beginning of the terminal line

So it's overriding what's already there on the string.

`end=''` the default for the print command is `end='\n'` (So that's why you don't need to add a new line after each print statement)

So by not printing a new line in the interactive shell you are just placing your cursor at the end of what you've printed on the terminal

```
>>> print("Hello", end='')
Hello>>> 

>>> print("Hello\rI will override", end='') 
I will override>>>
```

If you print normally, this is why you're next shell command doesn't end up in the middle of a string.

```
>>> print("Hello", end='\n')
Hello
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>>

>>> print("""Hello
... this is a multi line
... \rexample""")
Hello
this is a multi line
example
>>>
```

So why is it different when you run it from a script? It short answer it's not. It's just a bit of how the terminal you're using is displaying the output:

Example from bash:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat test.py  
carriage_return = "I will use a carriage\rreturn"

print(carriage_return)
print(carriage_return, end='\n')
print(carriage_return, end='')
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python test.py 
return use a carriage
return use a carriage
returnpi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

So from bash it just overrides the rest of what's printed with the $USER@$HOSTNAME

Same file from windows terminal:

```
Desktop> python .\Stackoverflow.py
return use a carriage
return use a carriage
return use a carriage
Desktop>
```

The reason you're just seeing "return" is down to the way the shell you're using determines when to start a newline.

Hopefully that helps clear it up.

Comment: I understand why the interactive shell works like it does,
my problem lies when I don't use the interactive shell and the 
output is "return" only.

Comment: Added some more examples, but the discrepancy that appears in on your screen will just be from how the shell/terminal you're using choses to display the lack of end of line being passed.